# Loading JSON data using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I've been trying to load my JSON data using JavaScript to create a table on my webpage but I constantly get an SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 546.

Part of my JSON code:

```
{
    "routes": [{
            "routeID": "1",
            "name": "Camden Town",
            "startLat": "51.541837",
            "startLng": "-0.139199",
            "endLat": "51.550396",
            "endLng": "-0.140526",
            "day": "Sunday",
            "time": "9am",
            "highlights": "Camden Lock. Camden Market. Roundhouse. Camden High Street. Electric Ballroom.",
            "trailImage": "route-placeholder-image.png"

        },
        {
            "routeID": "2",
            "name": "Regents Park",
            "startLat": "51.523751",
            "startLng": "-0.154577",
            "endLat": "51.541565",
            "endLng": "-0.161842",
            "day": "Sunday",
            "time": "10am",
            "highlights": "Rose Garden. Boating Lakes. Mosque. Devonshire Terrace. Open Air Theatre. Camden Lock. Regents Canal.",
            "trailImage": "route-placeholder-image.png"
        },
        {
```

and my JavaScript code:

```
    window.onload = getRoutes;
    
    let xhr = false;
    
    function getRoutes() {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        if (xhr) {
            xhr.open("GET", "data/routes.json", true);
            xhr.send();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = displayRoutes;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("statusmessage").innerHTML = "error";
        }
    }
    function displayRoutes () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                let dataText = "";
                for (let i in data.routes) {
                    if (data.routes[i].routeID >= 1) {
                        dataText += "<tr><td><strong>" +
                        data.routes[i].name + "</strong></td><td class='text-center'>" +
                        data.routes[i].day + "</td><td>" +
                        data.routes[i].time + "</td><td class='text-center'>" +
                        data.routes[i].highlights + "</td><td>" +
                        "<a href='" + data.routes[i].name.replace(/\s/g, '-').toLowerCase() +
                        ".html' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary'>Details</a>" +
                        "</td><tr>";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                document.getElementById("statusmessage").innerHTML = "Error. Could not perform the stated request Error: " + xhr.status;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas or hints of how do I make it work? Appreciate the help... Thank you

Comment: Please copy the JSON from the Nework tab of the DevTools (up to 550 chars), and paste that on the post. Maybe there's an illegal invisible character included in the JSON.

Comment: {
 "routes": [
 {
 "routeID" : "1",
 "name": "Camden Town",
 "startLat": "51.541837",
 "startLng": "-0.139199",
 "endLat": "51.550396",
 "endLng": "-0.140526",
 "day": "Sunday",
 "time": "9am",
 "highlights": "Camden Lock. Camden Market. Roundhouse. Camden High Street. Electric Ballroom.",
 "trailImage": "route-placeholder-image.png"

 },
 {
 "routeID" : "2",
 "name": "Regents Park",
 "startLat": "51.523751",
 "startLng": "-0.154577",
 "endLat": "51.541565",
 "endLng": "-0.161842",
 "day": "Sunday",
 "time": "10am"

Comment: There doesn't seem to be [anything wrong](https://jsfiddle.net/9a41s37x/) in the JSON ... You could try to feed all of it to a [validator](https://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: I've found the issue, no more errors regarding JSON but I think my JavaScript code is wrong as the table doesn't show up on my webpage

Comment: Yup, you're creating `dataText`, but never use it.

Comment: any hints on how to fix that? i'm quite new to JavaScript

Comment: Somewhere on your HTML code there's a table element waiting for content, which you've stored in `dataText`. Do something similar to what you've done with the error message in the `else` block.

Comment: okay I've managed to make it work, thank you for your help! appreciate it!